# Iterating over n-depth in tree like structure

Tags: java, tree, iterator

How to programmatically get n-depth iterator over tree like structure?
In the root i have

```
List<Node>
```

each Node have

```
Map<Integer,List<Node>>
```

which are n+1 depth.

I have fixed for 1 depth:

```
// DEPTH 1
nodeData.forEach(baseNode -> {
    baseNode.getChildNodes().entrySet().forEach(baseNodeChildeNodes -> {
            genCombOnePass(baseNodeChildeNodes, 2);
        });
});
```

and

```
// DEPTH 2
nodeData.forEach(baseNode -> {
    baseNode.getChildNodes().entrySet().forEach(baseNodeChildeNodes -> {
        baseNodeChildeNodes.getValue().forEach(childNodeEs -> {
            childNodeEs.getChildNodes().entrySet().forEach(childNode -> {
                genCombOnePass(childNode, 3);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

but i need to iterate ex. 1-9 depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of recursive function to achieve what you want:

```
static void depthTraversal(Node root, int depth, int maxDepth) {
    if (depth == maxDepth) { // if you reached max level - exit
        return;
    }
    if (root == null || root.getChildNodes() == null) { // if you reached null child - exit
        return;
    }
    root.getChildNodes().forEach((key, value) -> value.forEach(node -> {
        // do what you need with your nodes
        depthTraversal(node, depth + 1, maxDepth); // recursively go to next level
    }));
}
```